# Force rotate in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So I know objective-c is no longer being updated and is kind of left behind now but I'm still learning on how to code so it is perfect.

I have an app that I am creating with menues in portrait and the main game is in landscape. I have made the ViewControllers into landscape and when turning the device into landscape it works perfectly but when the device is kept in portrait the game is all messed up.

Could anyone help me with how to force rotate/make the game wait until the screen is portrait? The game looks really messed up portrait so I would prefer if the screen was forced to rotate.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't menus in landscape too? From a usability perspective (not answering the question), it may be rather frustrating to have to rotate from a portrait menu to a landscape game.  If they also have to rotate back & forth every time they need the menu, it will quickly get old. Consider playing w/the menu layout to make it landscape as well so it's a seamless experience for the player. In XCode you can set which orientations are supported to prevent rotation & only support landscape.

Comment: I have been considering it and it may look fairly good landscape. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The first sentence of your question is confused. Objective-C is a language. It is not left behind at all. It will be viable for a long time.

Comment: I know it will still be in use for a while but I cant seem to find any newer/good tutorials/lessons on it now but can find tons of swift. Thats why I feel its been left behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view controllers that need their orientation updated, add:

```
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

in their viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks! This did answer my question :)